# Solving the Poisson's equation using intergal transform method

Tags: fourier-transform, poissons-equation

Consider the following Poisson's equation;

$${\nabla}^2\phi=-f(\mathbf{r})$$

How can I solve for $\phi$ using integral transform?

I tried beginning with inverse fourier transform but just after I wrote few lines I do not know how to proceed..

$$f(\mathbf x)=∫dkf(\mathbf k)e^{ik⋅\mathbf x}$$

$$∇^2f(\mathbf x)=∇^2∫dkf(\mathbf 
 k)e^{ik⋅\mathbf x}=∫dkf(\mathbf  k)∇^2e^{ik⋅\mathbf 
 x}=-k^2∫dkf(\mathbf k)e^{ik⋅\mathbf x}$$

Can someone help me please.

Comment: Fourier transform is more appropriate, but you'll just end up with the Green's function anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming three-dimensional Cartesian coordinates, I would transform from space ($x$,$y$,$z$) to Fourier Domain ($X$,$Y$,$Z$)
\begin{equation}
(iX)^2\, \Phi + (iY)^2\, \Phi + (iZ)^2\, \Phi = -F(X,Y,Z)
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
F(X,Y,Z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y,z)\, e^{-ixX} e^{-iyY} e^{-izZ}\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,\text{d}z. 
\end{equation}
And then solve for
\begin{equation}
\Phi(X,Y,Z) = \frac{F(X,Y,Z)}{X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2}
\end{equation}
and finally hope to find the inverse transform
\begin{equation}
\phi(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{1}{2\pi}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(X,Y,Z)\, e^{ixX} e^{iyY} e^{izZ} \,\text{d}X\,\text{d}Y\,\text{d}Z. 
\end{equation}
by analytical integration, transform tables (can $\Phi$ be found as entry or product of entries?) or numerical approximations.

Comment: Can this problem be solved in 3 dimensions please

Comment: Yes, by a third transformation from $z$ to $Z$, I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @A.M.MElsayed Yes, it can be solved in terms of a convolution integral expression.